# Was Rosemary Sutcliff's The High Deeds of Finn MacCool influenced by James Macpherson's Ossian translations?

Tags: inspiration, rosemary-sutcliff, the-high-deeds-of-finn-maccool

In 1967, Rosemary Sutcliff published the children's novel [*The High Deeds of Finn MacCool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=The_High_Deeds_of_Finn_MacCool&oldid=808680928), which is a retelling of the stories of the Irish hunter-warrior [Fionn mac Cumhaill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fionn_mac_Cumhaill) and the [Fenian Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenian_Cycle).
The stories around Fionn mac Cumhaill or Finn McCool have also been used in one of the most famous literary forgeries in English literature: the [Ossian poems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossian) published by [James Macpherson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Macpherson)
in the 1760s. These Ossian poems quickly became very popular; for example, Werther reads from them in Goethe's *The Sorrows of Young Werther* (first published in 1774). But [Samuel Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Johnson#Final_works) already disputed their authenticity in his final works.

The fact that these publications were exposed as forgeries does not imply that they can't be used as a source of inspiration. So is there any evidence that Rosemary Sutcliff used James Macpherson's publications as a source?